# Why is Option not Traversable?

Tags: scala, collections

Is there any rational for `Option` not being `Traversable`?

In Scala 2.9, `Seq(Set(1,3,2),Seq(4),Option(5)).flatten` doesn't compile and simply having it to implement the `Traversable` trait seams rational to me. If it's not the case, there must be something I don't see that don't allow it. What is it?

PS: While trying to understand, I achieved awful things that compile, like:

```
scala> Seq(Set(1,3,2),Seq(4),Map("one"->1, 2->"two")).flatten
res1: Seq[Any] = List(1, 3, 2, 4, (one,1), (2,two))
```

PS2: I know I can write: `Seq(Set(1,3,2),Seq(4),Option(5).toSeq).flatten` or other ugly thing.

PS3: There seams to be work in the last month to make `Option` look more like `Traversable` without implementing it: [commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/001710d73eedbe3f23b7d704c772a8616ddf2f10#src/library/scala/Option.scala), [another commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/d188f6fdded6fdd9df3960d6085b9b80046c05ca#src/library/scala/Option.scala)

Comment: For language (or in this case library) design questions like this, it's usually best to ask the language (or library) designers directly. They are pretty responsive on the mailing list but only occasionally visit StackOverflow.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It would be nice to have a compiled answer on SO, though..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be challenges around having `flatMap` return an `Option` rather than a `Traversable`. Though that predates the whole 2.8 `CanBuildFrom` machinery.

The question was [asked](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/2-8-collections-tp2004910p2004922.html) once before on the mailing list but didn't elicit a response.

Here is an illustration:

```
sealed trait OptionX[+A] extends Traversable[A] {
  def foreach[U](f: (A) => U): Unit = if (!isEmpty) f(get)
  def get: A
  def isDefined: Boolean
  def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
}

case class SomeX[+A](a: A) extends OptionX[A] {
  override def isEmpty = false
  def get = a
  def isDefined = true
  def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B) = a
}

case object NoneX extends OptionX[Nothing] {
  override def isEmpty = true
  def get = sys.error("none")
  def isDefined = false
  def getOrElse[B](default: => B) = default
}

object O extends App {
  val s: OptionX[Int] = SomeX(1)
  val n: OptionX[Int] = NoneX
  s.foreach(i => println("some " + i))
  n.foreach(i => println("should not print " + i))
  println(s.map(_ + "!"))
}
```

The last line returns a `List("1!")` instead of `Option`. May be somebody can come up with a `CanBuildFrom` that would yield an `SomeX("1!")`. My attempt did not succeed:

```
object OptionX {
  implicit def canBuildFrom[Elem] = new CanBuildFrom[Traversable[_], Elem, OptionX[Elem]] {
    def builder() = new Builder[Elem, OptionX[Elem]] {
      var current: OptionX[Elem] = NoneX
      def +=(elem: Elem): this.type = {
        if (current.isDefined) sys.error("already defined")
        else current = SomeX(elem)
        this
      }
      def clear() { current = NoneX }
      def result(): OptionX[Elem] = current
    }
    def apply() = builder()
    def apply(from: Traversable[_]) = builder()
  }
}
```

I need to pass the implicit explicitly:

```
scala> import o._
import o._

scala> val s: OptionX[Int] = SomeX(1)
s: o.OptionX[Int] = SomeX(1)

scala> s.map(_+1)(OptionX.canBuildFrom[Int])
res1: o.OptionX[Int] = SomeX(2)

scala> s.map(_+1)
res2: Traversable[Int] = List(2)
```

**Edit:**

So I was able to work around the issue and have `SomeX(1).map(1+)` return an `OptionX` by having `OptionX` extend `TraversableLike[A, OptionX[A]]` and overriding `newBuilder`.

But then I get runtime errors on `SomeX(1) ++ SomeX(2)` or `for (i <- SomeX(1); j <- List(1,2)) yield (i+j)`. So I don't think it's possible have option extend `Traversable` and do something sane in terms of returning the most specific type.

Beyond feasibility, coding style wise, I'm not sure it's a good thing to have `Option` behave like a `Traversable` in all circumstances. `Option` represent values that are not always defined, while `Traversable` defines methods for collections that can have multiple elements in it like `drop(n)`, `splitAt(n)`, `take(n)`, `++`. Although it would offer convenience if `Option` was also a `Traversable`, I think it may make intent less clear.

Using a `toSeq` where necessary seems like a painless way to indicate that I want my option to behave like a `Traversable`. And for certain recurring use cases, there is the `option2Iterable` implicit conversion - so for instance this already works (they all return `List(1,2)`):

- `List(Option(1), Option(2), None).flatten`
- `for (i <- List(0,1); j <- Some(1)) yield (i+j)`
- `Some(1) ++ Some(2)`

Comment: IMO `Traversable` shouldn't define `++` or `drop` etc. `Traversable` should define as being able to traverse, not necessarily to build, or to alter. Surprisingly after these years it is still an issue

Answer (score 4):

It is not `Traversable` because you can't implement a `scala.collection.mutable.Builder` for it.

Well, it could be a Traversable even so, but that would result in a lot of methods that return `Option` now returning `Traversable` instead. If you want to see what methods are these, just look at the methods that take a `CanBuildFrom` parameter.

Let's take your sample code to demonstrate why:

```
Seq(Set(1,3,2),Seq(4),Option(5)).flatten
```

That ought to be equal to:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Now, let's consider this alternative:

```
Option(Set(1,3,2),Seq(4),Option(5)).flatten
```

What's the value of that?

Comment: `Option#apply` takes one parameter, and answer in that case is: `Option(Set(1,3,2)).flatten => Set(1,3,2)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in some cases with implicits applied the type would get less precise. You would still have an `Option` value, but the static return type would be something like `Iterable`, e. g. not the “most precise” one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm being dense, but I don't understand why anyone would need this.  Furthermore, it would require `None` to be `Traversable` as well which seems semantically dubious.

They say a design is finished not when there is nothing left to add, but rather nothing left to take away.  Which is not to say, of course, that the Scala standard library is perfect.

Comment: Touché.  However `Nil` and `None` mean quite different things.  `Nil` extends `List[Nothing]` and is the value of `List()`.  If `Nil` were not `Traversable` it would cause lots of problems :)

Comment: How about `Future.traverse(option)(f)` or `Future.sequence(option)`. I think you can equally argue that the quote from Antoine de Saint-Exupéry is an argument in favor of `Option` being `Traversable`. Right now we have "a `Traversable` is a thing that you can traverse over, except for an `Option` which has almost all of the behavior of a `Traversable` but that isn't one so you should have separate methods for `Option` and every other kind of collection." The thing we've added is an arbitrary distinction that doesn't logically exist.

Answer (score 0):

As of Scala 2.13, **[`Option` now extends `IterableOnce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/Option.html)**, which is basically the new `TraversableOnce` now that [`TraversableOnce` is deprecated](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) in favor of simpler type hierarchy. From the official scala website, `Option` is now defined as

```scala
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends IterableOnce[A] with Product with Serializable
```