# Add Option[T] to Vector[T]

Tags: scala

What is the best practice to perform such an operation? Add `T` to `Vector[T]` if `T` is `Some[T]` otherwise do nothing. This ugly thing works

```
val v: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3) ++ Some(5).toSeq
```

But converting an Option to a Seq is far from intuitive. I was thinking of defining an implicit for `Vector` and `Option` but I was wondering if there is something out of the box I can use.

I would expect for something like this to work

```
   val v: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3) :+ Some(5)
```

But apparently [`Option` is **NOT** `Traversable`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719491/why-is-option-not-traversable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `Vector(1, 2, 3) ++ Some(5).toSeq`, this is how it is usually done.

While experimenting with the code to answer your question I have found that (surprisingly to me) you do not have to write `toSeq` even in Scala 2.10 - 2.12,  thanks to `option2Iterable` defined in `scala.Option` companion object. This implicit conversion make sure `Option` can be used where `Iterable` is expected, which is enough for `Vector.++` operator.

Following works: `Vector(1, 2, 3) ++ Some(5)`

You do not need to use `toSeq` even when concatenating multiple options, like `Some(1) ++ Some(2)` - the result is `List(1, 2)`.

In Scala 2.13  `Option` is derived from `IterableOnce`, therefore even the implicit conversion is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

`Option` was made [`IterableOnce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) in Scala 2.13 by [Make Option extend IterableOnce #8038](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8038)

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends IterableOnce[A] with Product with Serializable
```

so the following should work Scala 2.13

```
Vector(1, 2, 3) ++ Some(5)
Vector(1, 2, 3) ++ None
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 5)
// res2: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would **pattern match** it.

```
val v: Vector[Int] = optional match {
  case Some(x) => Vector(1, 2, 3) :+ x
  case None => Vector(1, 2, 3)
}
```